# Can I use kindle-highlights gem with RubyMotion

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, rubymotion, kindle

I'm trying to use [kindle-highlights](https://github.com/speric/kindle-highlights) gem in RubyMotion. I found [motion-bundler](https://github.com/archan937/motion-bundler), that should help me bring these two together.

According to FAQ from motion-bundler, not every gem will work.

> **Can I use every random Ruby gem available?**
>
> Unfortunately, no. You can only use Ruby gems which do not require libraries (e.g. psych.bundle) and do not use string evaluation at runtime (for instance using class_eval with a String).

If I'm trying to use kindle-higlights I get the `uninitialized constant` error:

`` (main)> 2017-02-14 10:13:41.606 HelloMotion[60710:1987881] app_delegate.rb:26:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': uninitialized constant AppDelegate::KindleHighlights (NameError)
2017-02-14 10:13:41.610 HelloMotion[60710:1987881] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NameError', reason: 'app_delegate.rb:26:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': uninitialized constant AppDelegate::KindleHighlights (NameError) ``

So what i want to know is:

- Can I use this gem?
- Is this the error I should expect, if it is not meant to be?
- Does "do not require libraries" mean, any library or just some, that kindle-highlights is using?
- Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

- Only gems that support Ruby 1.9 will work RubyMotion does not support newer versions of Ruby.
- Gems that require a C-extension or depend on a Gem that requires a C-extension will not work
- Gems with eval will not work

**motion-bundler** is still a useful library and should help but the gem you want says it required Ruby 2.1.0, so I don't think it will work. If you want to try to make a gem RubyMotion compatible (without motion-bundler) you can try following this tutorial http://blog.motioninmotion.tv/gems-for-ruby-or-rubymotion/